# CakePHP HTML link

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, html-helper

I am trying to use CakePHP HTML Linker for the following code

```
<li class="iAdd"><a href="add"><span>Add Cuisine</span></a></li>
```

Since the span tag needs to be inside the a tag. am not able to get the output as need. Any suggestions on how to get it done ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable the escape option in your link code, like so:

```
<li class="iAdd">
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
    '<span>Add Cuisine</span>',
    array('action' => 'add'),
    array('escape' => false) // This line will parse rather then output HTML
); ?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can always use normal html in links:

```
$this->Html->link('<span>'.h($text).'</span>', array('action'=>'add'), array('escape'=>false));
```

Comment: note the h() if you plan on passing db input into your link then for security purposes (many programmers forget that while using escape=>false)

Comment: if the text is static i can use it directly ?

Comment: sure - if you know that it doesnt contain any html chars that could mess up your layout (< > " ...)